# How do I use data returned from PHP to build out an HTML table?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mongodb

I have a php file that is reaching out and touching a mongo db and building a bunch of table tags.  When I replace the script tag code below with the php code it works fine and builds out the table.

When I try to get the php results from the called page I manage to get the table text into the data variable ... if I alert it I see all the table tags and data that is generated from my .php page ... but I'm not sure how to embed that code inline in the HTML right after the th tags ... if I do a document.write(data) inside the script it seems to overwrite the whole page with just the data that was generated from the .php page ... it doesn't append it after the th row.  Thank you in advance for any advice.

```
            <table class="table table-striped table-hover">

                 <tr>
                    <th>Agency</th>
                    <th>POC</th> 
                    <th>POC Phone</th>
                    <th>Address</th>
                 </tr>          

                 <script>
                    var data_from_ajax;
                    $.get('build-agency-table.php', function(data) {
                      data_from_ajax = data;
                      alert(data);
                    });
                </script>

            </table>
```

And this is returned by the php script

```
<tr><td>BACODA</td><td>Kristi Smith</td><td>211.444.2222</td>
```

Comment: My mind is turning in circles trying to understand your question. Are you perhaps confused between javascript and PHP?

Comment: I don't think so.  I am using the $.get to call out to the .php file and it returns my table row data  (here is an example of that data: <tr><td>BACODA</td><td>Kristi Smith</td><td>211.444.2222</td> ... etc.) I get the data or data_from_ajax variable that contains all my table info (tr, td tags and data) what I want to do is append that text from the data variable after the table row of headers to fill out the rest of the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
        <table class="table table-striped table-hover">

             <tr>
                <th>Agency</th>
                <th>POC</th> 
                <th>POC Phone</th>
                <th>Address</th>
             </tr>  

             <tbody id="tablebody"></tbody>

             <script>
                var data_from_ajax;
                $.get('build-agency-table.php', function(data) {
                  data_from_ajax = data;
                  $('#tablebody').html(data);
                  alert(data);
                });
            </script>

        </table>
```

Comment: Whoa this one comes first, pick this. Though I still prefer putting script tag outside of the table.

Comment: Thanks so much that works perfect.  And yes Hendyanto..now that I see what's really happening I realize that the script piece can go back into one of my .js files or somewhere else for cleanup.

Comment: I agree the script tag should go outside. I thought I moved it but didn't. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think the script tag belong outside of the table.
And using the tbody thead will help you to differentiate the static (heading) and dynamic (from ajax) content.

```
 <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Agency</th>
            <th>POC</th> 
            <th>POC Phone</th>
            <th>Address</th>
        </tr> 
        </thead>
        <tbody id="to_fill">

        </tbody>
 </table>


<script>
       var data_from_ajax;
       $.get('build-agency-table.php', function(data) {
         data_from_ajax = data;
         $("#to_fill").html(data_from_ajax);
       });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the html content to a container using javascript.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>...</th>
        <th>...</th>
        <th>...</th>
    </tr>
    <tr id="myRow"></tr>
</table>

<script>       
    $.get('build-agency-table.php', function(data) {
      $("#myRow").html(data); //Add the html content into "myRow"  
    });
</script>
```